# Mean function of a random sequence

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I am given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$ which denotes the outcome $\zeta = a,b, \text{or }c$; $\mathcal{F}=$ all subsets of $\Omega$ and $P[\{\zeta\}]=1/3$ for each outcome $\zeta$. Furthermore, the following random sequence $X[n]$ is given as 
\begin{align*} 
X[n,a]&=3\delta[n]\\
X[n,b]&=u[n-1]\\
X[n,c]&=\cos (\pi n/2)
\end{align*}
I want to find the mean function $\mu_X[n]$ and the correlation function $R_{XX}[m,n]$.

Starting with the mean function I thought about calculating:
\begin{equation*}
\mu_X[n]=1/3(E\{X[n,a]\}+E\{X[n,b]\}+E\{X[n,c]\})
\end{equation*}
Would this be the right approach?

The correlation function could then be calculated as 
\begin{equation*}
R_{XX}[m,n]=E\{X[n]X[m]\}?
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close $\mu_X[n] = \tfrac 13( X[n,a]+X[n,b]+X[n,c])$

Because $\mathsf E(X[n]\mid \zeta=a) = X[n,a]$ and so forth, so the Tower Property (aka Law of Iterated Expectation, or Law of Total Expectation) sais:

$$\mu_X[n] ~{= \mathsf E(\mathsf E(X[n]\mid\zeta)) \\= \sum_{z\in\{a,b,c\}} \mathsf P(\zeta=z)\mathsf E(X[n]\mid \zeta=z)\\=\tfrac 13(X[n,a]+X[n,b]+X[n,c])}$$

Use this Tower Property to similarly find:
$$\sigma^2_X[n] ~=~ \mathsf E(X^2[n])-\mathsf E(X[n])^2$$

---

$$R_{X,X}[n,m] =\dfrac{\mathsf E(X[n]~X[m])-\mu_X[n]~\mu_X[m]}{\sqrt{\sigma^2_X[n]~\sigma^2_X[m]}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I calculated $E(X^2[n])$ to $1/3E(9\delta[n]+u[n-1]+\cos^2(\pi n/2))$. Is this correct? I have one other question: How can I see if X[1] and X[0] are independent?